# Creating a Search Box

Tags: javascript, function, search

What I am trying to do is allow the user to look for an artists based on the artist's name in the search box below (in HTML) and then presenting the user with the artist's name and a link to a different HTML page if the user's search matches an artist in the array.

The trouble is, when I click "search" the page goes back to the original page. I am not sure where the disconnect is. I am not sure if I am calling for the ID correctly; if the ID is in the right place; if the action is the correct on in the U.addEvent function; or if the search function is written correctly.

Any ideas?

RD

```
<body>
<div class="imgs"> <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="img/04.png" alt="img" /></a></div>
</div> 

    <div class="form">
    <form method="post" action="handler.php">
       <input name="textfield" id="searchBox" type="text" class="colortext"/>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var fakeDatabase = [];

var foxyShazam = {
    id: 'foxyShazam_FS',
    title: 'Foxy Shazam',
    artist: 'Foxy Shazam',
    price: '$14.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1968, 10, 22),
    quantity: 50,
    link: "albums/foxyShazam.html",]
};

var foxyShazam2 = {
    id: 'foxyShazam_FS_2',
    title: 'Foxy Shazam 2',
    artist: 'Foxy Shazam 2',
    price: '$14.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1968, 10, 22),
    quantity: 50,
    link: "albums/foxyShazam.html"]
};

var thriller = {
    id: 'thriller_MJ',
    title: 'Thriller',
    artist: 'Michael Jackson',
    price: '$12.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1982, 10, 30),
    quantity: 35,
    link: "albums/thriller.html"
};

var thriller2 = {
    id: 'thriller_MJ_2',
    title: 'Thriller 2',
    artist: 'Michael Jackson 2',
    price: '$12.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1982, 10, 30),
    quantity: 35,
    link: "albums/thriller.html"]
};

fakeDatabase.push(foxyShazam, foxyShazam2, thriller, thriller2);

//function displayAlbum() {
//    'use strict';
//    for (var i=0; i < fakeDatabase.length; i++) {
//        alert(fakeDatabase[i].title);}
//};
//displayAlbum(fakeDatabase);

var U = {
    $: function (id) {
        'use strict';
        if (typeof id === 'string') {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }
    },
    setText: function(id, message) {
        'use strict';
        if ( (typeof id == 'string')
        && (typeof message == 'string') ) {

            // Get a reference to the element:
            var output = this.$(id);
            if (!output) return false;

            // Set the text
            if (output.textContent !== undefined) {
                output.textContent = message;
            } else {
                output.innerText = message;
            }
            return true;
        } // End of main IF.
    },
    addEvent: function(obj, type, fn){
        'use strict';
        if (obj && obj.addEventListener) {
            obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        } else if (obj && obj.attachEvent) {
            obj.attachEvent('on' + type, fn);
        }
    },
    removeEvent: function(obj, type, fn) {
        'use strict';
        if (obj && obj.removeEventListner) {
            obj.removeEventListner(type, fn, false);
        }
        else if (obj && obj.removeEvent) {
            obj.removeEvent('on' + type, fn);
        }
    }
};

function search() {
    'use strict';
    var newSearch = U.$('searchBox');
        if (typeof newSearch == 'string') {
            if (!newSearch) 
                {return false;};
            if (newSearch.textContent !== undefined) {
                for (var i=0; i < fakeDatabase.length; i++) {
                    if (i == newSearch) {
                        var options = document.getElementById('options');
                        (options.innerText = ((fakeDatabase[i].artist + '\n') + (fakeDatabase[i].link));
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

U.addEvent(U.$('searchBox'), 'click', search());

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: pretty sure it should be `U.addEvent(..., ..., search)`, without the parentheses after `search`

Answer (score 0):

`search` returns nothing. But the event handler needs to be a function. So either you do `U.addEvent(U.$('searchBox'), 'click', search);` or make `search()` return an event handler.

Basically right now you are immediately invoking the search handler and your form does nothing.

You also have the `click` handler on an `input` field. That will be pretty much useless, since you don't want anything to happen when the user just clicks the input field.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes I see. @TheShellfishMeme already pointed out two of those:

**First**, you are using the return value of the `search` function as the event handler, instead of the `search` function itself:

```
// this calls the 'search' function and uses it's return value as event handler
U.addEvent(U.$('searchBox'), 'click', search())

// this uses the function 'search' as the event handler
U.addEvent(U.$('searchBox'), 'click', search)
```

**Second**, You are adding an `click` handler on the `input` element, which will result in firing the `search` function, everytime a user clicks the input field (click is a mouse event). I guess you really want the search function to fire when the user hits `ENTER` or the submit button.

To achieve that, add the `search` function as the handler for the `submit` event of your `form` element:

```
<form id="searchForm">
....
U.addEvent(U.$('searchForm'), 'submit', search)
```

**Third**, after your search function is fired, you need to make sure that the event doesn't proceed to the default event behaviour, which is POSTing the data. To fix that, you need an `event.preventDefault()`. But you also need to catch the `event` variable in your function definition:

```
function search (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  .....

}
```

You also have some minor syntax errors, which I tried to fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/rGcpX/2/